# Can I use IR2110 for two independent MOSFETs?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, driver

Can I use IR2110, and feed it with two independent PWM signals, to drive two independent MOSFETs, each controlling a separate motor? (or high side and low side inputs/outputs of this chip gonna affect each other?)

I.e. two of this circuit, each controlling a separate motor's speed... (and each motor's speed needs to be controlled independently).

[image]
<sub>(source: [bristolwatch.com](http://www.bristolwatch.com/picaxe/images/m1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet doesn't seem to indicate that there is any active cross conduction control, so the two channels are independent. If you want both to be low-side switched you can connect Vb to Vcc and Vs to COM.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe but you must compute deadtime needed to avoid cross conduction and use low side PWM to boost Vb for high side.

see [What's the purpose of diode between high side and low side supply voltage of IR2110?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414647/whats-the-purpose-of-diode-between-high-side-and-low-side-supply-voltage-of-ir2)

The circuit you show is just a low side switch which coasts the motor when off.  Thus it has no de-acceleration speed control and relies on motor load, FYI only.